# Set Python to custom-set y-axis minor tick mark frequency

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, axis-labels

This question is related to plotting minor tick mars on the y-axis in a Python plot with
matplotlib.

Here is the code that I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_facecolor('white')

x = [1,2,3]
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plt.plot([3,2,1], label="test2")
plt.xticks()
plt.yticks()
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
plt.show()
```

When I generate this plot, I am not getting any minor tick marks.

I have attached here the plot that this code gives me.
[image]

Is it possible for me to display the minor tick marks for the y-axis here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set what ticks you want in plt.yticks() , the input can be a numpy array which you generate beforehand

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_facecolor('white')

yticks = np.arange(1,3,0.2)

x = [1,2,3]
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plt.plot([3,2,1], label="test2")
plt.xticks()
plt.yticks(yticks)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
plt.show()
```

which gives you :

[image]